# Docker .NET Web API Dev Certs "Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." on Some Endpoints

Tags: docker, api, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-core

**Update**: It appears to be some sort of certificate error since I added the following to my API controllers and calls are able to be made:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    private static HttpClient _httpClient;


    public MyController()
    {
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    }
...
}
```

However, I am still unsure what the issue is since I should be able to perform API calls with the self-signed cert. How do I remove the need to have `HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator`?

**Original**

I am developing a .NET 6 web API Docker container targeting Linux while my host environment is Windows. I can access all endpoints when running locally using `dotnet run` and building the production build with `dotnet publish -c Release -o out` and `dotnet out/my-app.dll`.

However, when I run the app inside a docker container, only one endpoint is accessible while the others have a 404 Not Found error: `Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.` Firstly, where is the inner exception. I cannot seem to find it in the Chrome dev tools or in my API tool (Insomnia.rest). Secondly, I believe I have configured the dev cert correctly.

These are my steps:

1. Run `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` and check certmgr.exe if the cert was actually deleted and delete if needed.
2. Create a new cert with `dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p {password here}`.
3. Trust the cert with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

**Note**: I'm using a private container repo but the image is the stock one that can be found on Dockerhub.

```
FROM myprivaterepo/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM myprivaterepo/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.4-bullseye-slim-amd64

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000

COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mantis-server.dll"]
```

Next I build the container: `docker build -t my-app .`

Then, I run the app: `docker run --rm -it -p 5001:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="password here" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -v ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro -v ~/devsecrets:/.microsoft/usersecrets my-app`

There are three endpoints: `/api/weatherforecast`, `/api/users?userId=1`, and `/api/cart?userId=1&cartId=1`. I am able to access `/api/weatherforecast` without issue, but the other two endpoints result in the `Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`

I'm not sure what the issue may be. Each of these endpoints is handled by a separate controller. There is a note in Insomnia that reads: `* Re-using existing connection! (#10) with host localhost` but I'm not sure what that means.

If you need any more information, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: did you checked docker logs ? if there any exception logged ?

Comment: I did try using docker logs, but I think that because this is using a build of the app inside the container, there are no logs. I only get logs that are informational and show the application starting and where the root path is unfortunately. I ran `docker logs --details -f myContainer`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I fixed it by the way in the bottom :

First this is my docker file :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Shoppify.Market.App.Api/Shoppify.Market.App.Api.csproj", "Shoppify.Market.App.Api/"]
COPY ["Shoppify.Market.App.Infrastructure/Shoppify.Market.App.Infrastructure.csproj", "Shoppify.Market.App.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Shoppify.Market.App.Identity/Shoppify.Market.App.Identity.csproj", "Shoppify.Market.App.Identity/"]
COPY ["Shoppify.Market.App.Service/Shoppify.Market.App.Service.csproj", "Shoppify.Market.App.Service/"]
COPY ["Shoppify.Market.App.Persistence/Shoppify.Market.App.Persistence.csproj", "Shoppify.Market.App.Persistence/"]
COPY ["Shoppify.Market.App.Domain/Shoppify.Market.App.Domain.csproj", "Shoppify.Market.App.Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Shoppify.Market.App.Api/Shoppify.Market.App.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Shoppify.Market.App.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Shoppify.Market.App.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Shoppify.Market.App.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

EXPOSE 5107
EXPOSE 7107

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Shoppify.Market.App.Api.dll"]
```

Actually when you want to redirect your application to ssl port, you have to generate its certificate, therefore do it in the docker-compose.yml file like me :

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    myapi:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "5107:5107"
        - "7107:7107"
      volumes:
        - ./Shoppify.Market.App.Api/appsettings.Development.json:/app/appsettings.json
        - ./Shoppify.Market.App.Api/values.json:/app/values.json
        - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      depends_on:
        - sqlserver
      environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5107
        - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=https://+:7107
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=12345678
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
        # dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here } AND THEN dotnet dev-certs https --trust
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    sqlserver:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
      environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "@Li12345678"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

After "environment" section and that last two lines ( I mean -> ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password & ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path) will generate certificate. My application ran by this instructions.
Don't forget that run this in the cmd (dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here } AND THEN dotnet dev-certs https --trust).
 I Hope I could fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ali-khancherli! Unfortunately, following these steps did not resolve my problem. I tried regenerating the dev certs in a cmd terminal and trusting the certs but there wasn't any change in the results. I think it might be an issue with my build since I'm developing on Windows but deploying on Linux containers and the certs might not work. Are you developing on Windows and deploying on Linux containers? Thanks!

Comment: Hi dear. I am so sorry about that but I just forgot something when I was writing this solution. Have you tried this code in you program class? builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://+:5107", "https://+:7107");  Please add this line under the var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); I hope again this will work. About that your question, yes I develop my program in the windows and deploy it in the linux. Of course that  I did it as test to learn how docker works.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, Ali. I did try to use `builder.WebHost.UseUrls(...)` but it doesn't work for me right now. It seems it is some sort of ca cert problem but I don't know why.